# add dynamically images to a fixed height and width DIV

Tags: c#, html, ajax

I am trying to add images and create a slide show in a fixed size div, when I add thumbnail image I would like to have for example 5 thumbnail side by side nad then move to the next row, I am using Ajax ReorderList to add images,how can I achieve this?

any idea?

Thank in advance

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at jQuery and the [Galleria plugin](http://devkick.com/lab/galleria/).

Look at the demo links and see if they're similar to what you want to achieve.  Also the plugin behavior and appearance can be customized extensively.

jQuery is really an amazing tool.